# individual command running but not batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line

I have the below command which runs perfectly fine on command prompt

```
start "heythere" "c:\script\ABC.XYS.CreateXML.exe" -SiteCollectionUrl:"http://site-prd" -TargetPath:"C:\destFolder" -LoginName:"GLOBAL\username"
```

However when I save the exaack command in a batch file and execute it, it doesn't run at all

I really can't figure out the problem.

Comment: _"It doesn't run at all" is pretty vague. Any error? Program starts but crashes?

Comment: I am absolutly no expert at all and this basicially is a random guess but have you tried to deliver the arguments with 
'-SiteCollectionUrl "http://site-prd"' rather than '-SiteCollectionUrl:"http://site-prd"'?

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti yes it crashes. can I somehow see the reason for crashing???

Comment: It would be helpful to see the contents of the batch file.

Comment: @rrirower it is the same that i have posted, just replaced the words but the punctuations are the same

Comment: How does it `crash` ?

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out. As the contents of the file were generated via code, there were issues with its encoding. Thus changing the encoding to ASCII solved the issue.